# Woocommerce place category over the title in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use this code to place category under the title in woocommerce cart. How can I place category over the title in woocommerce cart?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'bbloomer_cart_item_category', 9999, 3 );
 
function bbloomer_cart_item_category( $name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
 
   $product = $cart_item['data'];
   if ( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
      $product = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() );
   }
 
   $cat_ids = $product->get_category_ids();
 
   if ( $cat_ids ) $name .= '<br>' . wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . ' ', '</span>' );
 
   return $name;
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a name to the end and override `$name`. I revised your code. try the below code.

```
function bbloomer_cart_item_category( $name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
 
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() );
    }
 
    $cat_ids = $product->get_category_ids();
 
    if ( $cat_ids ) $name = wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . ' ', '</span>' ).'<br>' . $name ;
 
    return $name;
 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'bbloomer_cart_item_category', 9999, 3 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]